# Out of scope variable in jinja2 template started throwing error after i updated to jinja2 2.9

Tags: python-2.7, ansible, jinja2

I am generating some configurations with jinja2 templates (with Ansible 2.2) and my previously running scripts started giving me error after i updated my python modules. After a lot of debugging, i identified the problem. The problem was that following code snippet was working fine until i updated jinja2 to 2.9

```
    {% for dictValue in someDictVar -%}
#something something
{% endfor -%}

#This var is used outside its scope. was working earlier but not anymore.
{% if dictValue.someVar is defined -%}
...
```

why was out of scope thing working earlier and why did it start to break in 2.9 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excerpt from [Jinja 2.9 release notes](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/blob/fc5be479ddb3ffd2687607aada5a53bd5304f060/CHANGES#L173):

> Greatly changed the scoping system to be more consistent with what template designers and developers expect.

Also there are numerous fixes/changes to scope system in 2.9.1-2.9.4.

Using variable out of its scope was definitely a but that was fixed.

Comment: Well i did not realize the relation when i first quick read the release notes. Thanks for pointing it out.